# Swift - SwipingController Programmatic - button doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, programmatic-config

I created the SwipingController app.
The application was supposed to have the functionality of scrolling with gestures and a management bar with 2 buttons and UIPageControl.

For now, these buttons were supposed to print only a text message in the console, but it doesn't.

```
 let nextButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("NEXT", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleNextButton), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}()
@objc func handleNextButton() {
    print("Next Botton Pressed")
}
```

I wanted to add the whole page management bar in a separate file.

When it goes to the main controller, the whole functionality work.

I don't want to paste all the code, so it gives a link to the git

https://github.com/SebaKrk/SwipingControllerProgrammatic.git

[Picture from simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmklK.png)

Comment: I had a look at your project. Your button is within a UICollectionViewCell. You should look at using the Delegate pattern to handle actions when working with cells.

Comment: ok , i will implement the delegate pattern and pass it here to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that you set your target right in the setup code of your `UIButton`

```
let previousBotton : UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("PREV", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePreviousButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
```

It seems like the `self` is not initialized at this point. Because this code is run before your `init` was run.

So you have to set the `target` of the Button after you called `super.init` then it works.